# Regex remove symbols only on left and right side of string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string that contains a lot of noise and I only want to remove the symbols on left and right part of my string.

```
|«_ Date: 23/12/18 16:41 ($123) :}‘'
```

With my current approach I can remove all of them but it includes the symbols at centre as well, which I do not intend to do.

```
re.sub(r"[^a-zA-z0-9,./$ ' ' -]", "", s)
```

My ideal result would be like this

```
Date: 23/12/18 16:41 ($123)
```

Comment: Need more specifics about your requirement. Do you define the start of your string by a leading space i.e. _string of random characters_ <space> _Start of string_? And does it always end with a final space character too?

Comment: The string is generated by OCR algorithm and sometimes contain spaces at both ends.

Comment: Why not filter out the correct parts instead of removing those symbols?

Comment: @CtheSky Presumably there isn't a steady pattern in the correct parts and may contain non-alphanumeric characters too.

Comment: @CtheSky It's hard knowing the correct parts because the input data are coming from various sources.

Comment: @RexLow Is it right then to assume that your valid string always start with a valid alphanumeric character, can contain any characters in between and ends with a closing parenthesis ```)```?

Comment: @kerwei yes you are right

Comment: [`(?i)^[^a-z\d()]*|[^a-z\d()]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/biJC9l/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from @potato works great for my use case.

The relevant regex command would be

**Solution**

```
re.sub(r"(?i)^[^a-z\d()]*|[^a-z\d()]+$", "", s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very rough pattern for now, with quite a lot of caveats. It satisfies your example string above but I can foresee that you may get a lot of false matches. It's difficult to refine further since I do not know what the string structure looks like.

```
^(.*?)(?:[0-9a-zA-Z].*?\))(.*?)$
```

The pattern above captures all leading characters as group 1 and all trailing characters after your closing parenthesis as group 2. However, if there's another pair of parenthesis within the valid string, before the ending `(123)` it'll mess it up. Please see the example below.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/JikTHo/1

Comment: Your solution works partially but if there are more symbols on both sides then it would not get removed. Appreciate the effort.